# How to calculate TPH and TPS in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have 20 threads with 100 users each thread have different tranx's like 1st TG 6 and 2 nd TG 5 ....so on after completion of load test i want to calculate TPH and TPS could any one please let me know

Answer (score 0):

According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).

So for example if your test was running for 10 minutes and generated 3000 requests:

- TPS: 3000 requests per 10 minutes means 300 requests per minute means 5 requests per second
- TPH: 300 requests per 10 minutes means 1800 requests per hour

Alternatively you [can run JMeter in non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) and open the resulting .jtl file with JMeter Listener like [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) or [Summary Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) - both will show you the throughput.